# Monitoring a folder using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

This script will monitor a folder, if new images are created, move them to the image folder. Very simple.

But I got it partially working. The problem is only old images are moved; newly created ones don't.

I start with an empty folder, download an image (1.jpg) to the folder, nothing is moved to the Z: drive. Then I download another image (2.jpg) to that folder, only 1.jpg is moved to Z: drive; 2.jpg stays where it is. Seems like the newly created are never moved.

```
$folder = "C:\\Doc\\Files"
$dest = "C:\\Doc\\Files\\images"
$filter = "*.jpg"

$fsw = new-object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
    IncludeSubDirectories=$false
    NotifyFilter = [System.IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}

$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {

    Start-Sleep -s 10
    Move-Item -Path C:\Doc\Files\*.jpg C:\Doc\Files\images
}
```

**Update:**

After I add "Start-Sleep -s 10" before move-item, it works now.  But is there a better solution?

Comment: it sounds like the new files are still locked by their writing process at the time you attempt to copy them. have you considered sleeping the thread for a few seconds? how often do images get added on average?

Comment: only have a few images added to the folder everyday.  I can wait for a few seconds, but not sure how to do that.

Comment: I added "Start-Sleep -s 10", now it works, but still looking see if there's a better solution.

Comment: you may need to try to open the file for write, and see if it throws an exception (it will if its write-locked by another thread/process). see this answer on StackOverflow. its in .net so you shouldn't have too much trouble reformatting for powershell. just loop until there is no exception, or a timeout has elapsed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304/how-to-check-for-file-lock

Comment: another options is, since last-write updated indicates that the write is complete, but may not indicate locks released, you can try copying the file instead of moving it. then after copy is complete, delete it as a separate operation. you can usually read a locked file for copy, you just can't open it for write, or change its descriptors (name, path, etc). perhaps copying it first will give the writing process a few nanoseconds to clean up before the delete occurs.